# Upload user's profile pics to imgur without making user authenticate to imgur

Tags: image, file-upload, hosting, imgur

How do you upload user images to imgur without making user authenticate to imgur ie, I would like to upload on behalf of the application(subscribed to freemium plan) not the user. I came across the oauth api for imgur but I think I don't want that ?

I want to upload profile pics of users to imgur but without making users aware of this fact or them needing to register/sign in for imgur.

Answer (score 0):

Register your imgur app from this [link](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient) and save client keys.

After that you can upload images anonymously and retrieve image link as [this API doc](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload) guide.